# USB 3.0 mini dock not working on 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hdmi, dock

I'm trying to set up my USB 3.0 mini dock (https://en.j5create.com/products/jud380). So far, I have been able to get all of the ports to work except for the HDMI port.

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```bsh
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 06cb:1ac3 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 0711:5601 Magic Control Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 003 Device 011: ID abcd:1234 Unknown 
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And, `lspci`

```bsh
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0c03 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I have tried following the `loader.conf` steps outlined in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/umct.4freebsd.html by adding `umct_load="YES"` to `/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf`. The `/boot/efi/loader` path did not exist before I attempted this step, so I do not know if this new file is being loaded.

**Edit**

Given that all of the ports within the dock are detected except for the HDMI, how might I go about troubleshooting the HDMI port only?

Comment: Why are you trying to install Windows drivers? Everything in that dock is natively supported except the video outputs. Those are likely to be DisplayLink. Drivers here: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for taking a second to comment Gabriela. I'm trying Windows because what I've read online indicates there is no support for this brand and I've heard the same from their customer support. I'll see if DisplayLink will play nice with it.

Comment: Pretty much all USB graphic devices are DisplayLink. Anyway, your question is essentially a [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). [Edit] your question to ask  for help with making the docking station work, and include the output of `lsusb`. Because you want your docking to work, you don't want to install any windows drivers.

Comment: [According to DisplayLink](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/544333-displaylink-software-compatibility-with-3rd-party), j5create products use Magic Control Technology (MCT) hardware. I am not aware of Linux drivers for those adapters, but you can of course try to find one yourself. I am pretty sure that this won't work using ndiswrapper.

Comment: @danzel - I'm assuming [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/umct.4freebsd.html) is for an older MCT USB technology. I tried implementing the `loader.conf` as described in my updated question.

Comment: @TylerSN that is for a USB to RS-232 (serial port) adapter.

Comment: @danzel - Thanks. Given that all of the ports within the dock are detected except for the HDMI, are you able to offer guidance on how I go about troubleshooting the HDMI port only?

Comment: any chance a newer kernel might support it? you could test another kernel with ukuu or you could boot a live ubuntu 19.04 usb to see if it detects the hdmi port on your dock.

Comment: @TylerSN sadly, if there are no linux drivers available for their hardware, it just won't work. They only offer drivers for Windows and MacOS on their homepage and they are closed-source, meaning that the only one who could create a linux driver are MCT themselves. There is also no standard for video output via USB 3.0, therefore all manufacturers produce proprietary drivers for their specific hardware. If possible, try to return it for a refund and buy an adapter with DisplayLink hardware. That's the only manufacturer I know of that has excellent Linux driver support.